# How to clone my OpenShift Application to git

Tags: git, github, openshift

I created a Application from open-shift. I want to clone it to git-hub but i failed.
After lo-gin to my open-shift account from command prompt i ran it:

```
$ git clone <git_URL> <directory to create>
```

I made a git repository and find git_URL from web-console. 
But it is not working.
Error Message is:

fatal: could not create leading directories of 'https://github.com/torvalds/linux': Invalid argument

Can anyone please give the example of

```
$ git clone <git_URL> <directory to create>
```

Need Help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is not working? Do you have an error message?

Comment: Sir, i edited my post please see the error message :)

Comment: is there a space in your link, or it is a writing error?

Comment: Does your GitHub repo (that you are trying to clone) exist?

Comment: Can you please give me a example of 
$ git clone <git_URL> <directory to create>

Comment: Yes, sir that existed i just change the name here :)

Comment: A valid command would be `git clone https://github.com/something/some.git <directory to create>`

Comment: you can go in the folder where you want to clone it and then just do `git clone <your URL>`

Comment: ok thanks sir, but what should i write inside <directory to create>

Comment: normally it should be empty, for creating a git repo

Comment: ok thanks sir i clone it to:
ssh://54861d8be0b8cd9d190000d2@alchemistic-rajkin.rhcloud.com/~/git/alchemistic.git/

but i want to get the http/https link of that git_URL
How could i find?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to push an application you created through openshift to a github repository. The following article should help you:

https://forums.openshift.com/how-to-keep-a-github-repository-and-an-openshift-repository-in-sync

You will need to create a blank repository on your github, add it as a remote in your application's git configuration, then push to it with `git push remote_name master`.

```
git remote add github <github repo url>
git push github master
```

Answer (score 0):

First install ruby and install rhc. And setup your rhc with

```
$ rhc setup
```

command after that

```
$ git clone <git_URL>
```

for more information goto this [openshift developer site](https://developers.openshift.com/managing-your-applications/client-tools.html)